# Make div fixed at one point in html

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a div containing two buttons and I want that div to be fixed at a place and If I resize the browser It shouldn't changes it's position.

I tried using position:fixed but not working and when resizes the position is changing.

This is my CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
    body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/bgPat3.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.Imagebuttons
{
    position:absolute;
    top:494px;
    right:337px;
}
```

This is my DIV container:

```
<div class="Imagebuttons">
             <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Image1.png" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/Image2.png" /><br />
</div>
```

This is how it actually looks now:

Before resizing:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css `left` instead of `right`, this way it will stay on the same spot.

By using `right` you specify padding from the right side of your browser's window/element container. And by re-sizing your window you change the position of your right side, but the padding is still the same.
Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CV34X/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanks once again for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't change it position, since you are using `position:absolute`.
However, you might want to add a `width` and `height` to `div.Imagebuttons` to prevent it size changes as the window is resizing.

```
.Imagebuttons{
    position:absolute;
    top:494px;
    right:337px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: @Derek-Thanks for your reply,I have changed it but it shows me the same.

Answer (score -1):

If your div is inside another div that has position:relative this can happen.

Put your absolute div just inside body tag to test.

Comment: @rogelware-Thanks for your reply,I don't have any other div inside that.And I have tried by searching many questions but it did not suit my problem.